# Is there a standalone alternative to do binary release of a Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, server, package, operating-system

I am planning to create an open source home media system using Node.js and other technologies like database and object storage.

As it's open source, anyone can build the source code and deploy it on their system.But, I also want to release it as a binary for easy installation and setup.

Can anyone suggest a universal solution for all operating systems and possibly for all architectures included.

I haven't tried any solutions as I have not started with the project yet. My knowledge about system package managers and automation scripts are limited and finding a universal solution for all systems is difficult.

Comment: Why not try to search first? Finding a universal solution for all systems is not "difficult", I think you didn't even search. Most projects use pkg https://github.com/vercel/pkg which can compile to anything your heart can desire.